# Student Array menu

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm coding a menu to store names into an array, then giving options to add/delete students and search for a particular student as well, but I cant seem to find out how to set the array so that I can use it in other options, cause, for example, my code only allows me to input names when I use option 1, but it doesnt keep these names in the array when I choose option 3 to search for a name within the array, it just shows up as null for every slot in the array.

Another problem I am having is about how I can delete students, obviously it would be really easy if the name is at the end of the array but what if the name is in the middle, how would I be able to delete the name, shift all the other names down one slot so that there are no gaps in the array?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab10Ex2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice = 0;
        int[] stringArray = {};

        do{         

        String[] stringarray = new String[20];

            System.out.println("----------------MENU---------------");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1. Add Students");
            System.out.println("2. Delete Students");
            System.out.println("3. Search for student");
            System.out.println("4. Print all Students");
            System.out.println("5. exit");

            Scanner scanchoice = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = scanchoice.nextInt();

            if (choice ==1){

                    Scanner scannames = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.println("Please enter the student names into the array");

                int i = 0;

                for(i = 0; i<stringarray.length; i++){

                    String temp =scannames.nextLine();

                    stringarray[i]=temp.toLowerCase();

                    if(i==(stringarray.length-1)){
                        System.out.println("successfully filled up array fully");
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
            }

            if(choice==2){

            }

            if(choice==3){

                for(int p = 0; p<stringarray.length; p++){

                                    System.out.println(stringarray[p]);

                }
                                int x=0;
                                Scanner scannames1 = new Scanner(System.in);

                                System.out.println("Enter name of student you want to search for: ");
                                System.out.println();
                                String search=scannames1.nextLine();
                                String searchName=search.toLowerCase();

                                for(int p=0;p<20;p++){
                                    if(searchName.equals(stringarray[p])){
                                        x=1;

                                        }
                                    else{
                                        x=0;
                                    }
                                }

                                if(x==1){
                                    System.out.println("We have a match in our database for "+ searchName);
                                }
                                else if (x==0){
                                    System.out.println("No match for "+ searchName);
                                }
                            }

                            if (choice ==4){
                                System.out.println("List of names:");

                                for(int p = 0; p<stringarray.length; p++){
                                    System.out.println(stringarray[p]);
                                }
                            }
        }while(choice!=5);
    }
}
```

Comment: move String[] stringarray = new String[20];  to just before the do-while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Lab10Ex2 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int choice = 0;
    int[] stringArray = {};
    String[] stringarray = new String[20];

    do{         




        System.out.println("----------------MENU---------------");

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1. Add Students");
        System.out.println("2. Delete Students");
        System.out.println("3. Search for student");
        System.out.println("4. Print all Students");
        System.out.println("5. exit");



        Scanner scanchoice = new Scanner(System.in);
        choice = scanchoice.nextInt();

        if (choice ==1){

            Scanner scannames = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter the student names into the array");
            System.out.println();

            int i = 0;


            for(i = 0; i<stringarray.length; i++){



                String temp =scannames.nextLine();

                stringarray[i]=temp.toLowerCase();

                if(i==(stringarray.length-1)){
                    System.out.println("successfully filled up array fully");
                    System.out.println();
                }


            }







        }

        if(choice==2){


        }


        if(choice==3){


            for(int p = 0; p<stringarray.length; p++){

                System.out.println(stringarray[p]);

            }
            int x=0;
            Scanner scannames1 = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter name of student you want to search for: ");
            System.out.println();
            String search=scannames1.nextLine();
            String searchName=search.toLowerCase();

            for(int p = 0; p < stringarray.length ;p++){
                if(searchName.equals(stringarray[p])){
                    x=1;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    x=0;
                }
            }



            if(x==1){
                System.out.println("We have a match in our database for "+ searchName);
            }
            else if (x==0){
                System.out.println("No match for "+ searchName);
            }
        }





        if (choice ==4){
            System.out.println("List of names:");

            for(int p = 0; p<stringarray.length; p++){

                System.out.println(stringarray[p]);
                System.out.println();


            }

        }










    }while(choice!=5);

}

}
```

Things you were doing wrong:

1. Instantiating the array in the do while loop.
2. Not breaking out of the loop if a search entity was found in the array.

Use ArrayList if you want to avoid wasting space in arrays after deletion. If you are bound to this with simple arrays, you can do this:

> Place null at index from which you deleted.Create a temporary array with same size as the original one with all null values. Copy all the elements from the original array to the temporary one but skip elements that are null. Point the original array to the new array.

AND AVOID HARD CODING ARRAY LENGTHS!

Comment: -1; not a fan of just giving a student the code.  Point out what went wrong and where instead of giving them their assignment in a complete form.

Comment: I did point it out. And of course you are right in your sense. Students learn by figuring out things themselves.

Answer (score 2):

```
    int choice = 0;
    int[] stringArray = {};

    do{         

        String[] stringarray = new String[20];
```

Delete the `int[] stringArray` line (you don't refer to it anywhere).

Move the `String[] stringarray` up, outside the loop.

As to deleting, you either have to code that yourself (move everything past the deleted item up one in the array), or use one of the collection classes provided with Java (instead of a native array), which handle deletion for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
do{         

    String[] stringarray = new String[20];
```

On each iteration of your Do { ... } loop, you're recreating the stringarray variable, thus clearing it. If you move this outside of the loop, your student entries will be maintained.

As for deleting, if you're not required to use an array of strings, I would recommend using an ArrayList. It will allow you to easily remove specific entries without worrying about the other entries. Otherwise, yes, the simplest thing to do would be to move all of the other entries down one slot to avoid gaps